# VB6 to VB.NET graphics panel Conversion 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, panel, vb6-migration

While converting from vb6 to vb.net i am facing this issue

> Error 310 'AutoRedraw' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent for the AutoRedraw property. In .NET you should do all of the drawing in the Paint event.

You my try `[Form Name].DoubleBuffered = True` as an alternative